# Why does Mathematica 10.3.1 fail me on : Integrate[(x^3) [Log[2 Sin[x]]]^8, {x, 0, Pi}]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

All it gives me is a pretty restatement of my original request. When I use WolframAlpha PRO, I get a result of 624510 and a visual representation of the area in question. I know the ends of the interval [0,pi] are problematic. What am I doing wrong? The 'definite integral' in WolframAlpha PRO was given  x^3*ln(2*sin(x))^8  in the 'function to integrate' box. Ideally, what would be best, is if both programs would give me a closed form expression, if it exists. NIntegrate was not helpful either. You should know I am very new to Mathematica.

Comment: Partly because square brackets are reserved in *Mathematica* for containing arguments to functions. Parentheses *()* are the only symbols used in *Mathematica* for grouping terms and factors in mathematical expressions. That said, I ran that integral in my copy of *Mathematica* and it returned unevaluated, suggesting that it doesn't know an analytic form (which doesn't mean it doesn't exist; perhaps the expression could be massaged into a form that can be integrated analytically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't look to be an analytic form of the integral (as mentioned in the comment by march), though numeric integration does match the expected result.

```
NIntegrate[x^3*Log[2*Sin[x]]^8, {x, 0, π}]
(*624510.*)
```

You can plot the corresponding area with

```
Plot[x^3*Log[2*Sin[x]]^8, {x, 0, π}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]